# Link into Application Insights UI

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a self-developed dashboard on which I can see certain errors from my apps. I also have Application Insights.

Now I'd like to have links in the graphs of my custom dashboard to the search section of AI with the right filters to find the log events that correspond there.

The URLs in the Azure Portal are horrible though.

Is there any way to do that at all?

Comment: You want to add a link to dashboard which is pointing to the `Search` in app insight?

Comment: Yes, but with search parameters coming from what I clicked on in the dashboard. The point being that I see an error on the dashboard and want to find it quickly to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple ways of pinning filtered views:

1. Pin Analytics query (as a chart). Click through will navigate to Analytics with this query opened
2. Apply needed filters on Failure / Performance blades and pin them. Click through will navigate to these blades and will preserve all configured filters

Comment: Pinning isn't enough. The filter parameters would depend on what I clicked on in my dashboard.